# Rest API JWT token based authentication security | laravel/dingo/jwt

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel, authentication

I am using JWT token based authentication for the authenticating my REST APIs exposed to mobile apps. I have a login API where the user will be hitting to and get a JWT back as a response. App has to use the JWT token for the rest of the requests. One question that struck during the development is.

Once I give an authentication token to the user, he has access to rest of the set of APIs.

User **1** with JWT token **T1** trying to access resources of user **2** is possible in my current design which is a flaw in my system. On each request do I have to check whether the user id in the token and the user id for which the process is requested matches and then proceed? or is there any better way this is been handled some other way?

I am using laravel framework with dingo rest and JWT lib.

**Update**

Eg :

I as an individual got the endpoints from the app. I logged in and received my jwt token which will be valid across rest of my resources. Now to get a list of products I have added using a different user id.I can do it this way

My JWT token in the header

```
GET /products/3  and 3 is not my user id!
```

In this case, Im just validating  a jwt token, which will validate it and respond with the resource which is not MINE!

Comment: you can use Laravel's new Gate/Auth system to do that. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: It is imho quite common to use it this way, you should be good the way it is!

**More detail**:
The point here is that the token is "obscure enough" so that there is an negligable chance a non-authorized user is obtaining the token from an authorized user. In your example this means, that user 2 can with a very high probabilty not guess the token that user 1 is using.

Of course this way may be prune to man-in-the-middle-attacks, so you should be sure to only transfer the tokens over a secure connection. I suggest "HTTPS only". Also, you may think about only sending and receiving the tokens in the header, so they are not exposed in any content views.

**As a bit more background**: Think about how [PHP "standard" session cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) are working: The user (client) gets a session ID in a cookie and sends it back. This is basically the same as you are doing here with the JWT, as user 2 could also somehow steal the cookie from user 1 here, and act on his behalf. JWT even adds you a level with which you can easily confirm that you actually issued the token (provided you are using the [RSA-keypair-style](http://jwt.io/introduction/) approach), which i think is an advantage over the PHP session ID cookie approach.

Comment: As I understand your updated question, you do not do any [ACL](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List) checks for the user then, right? I would recommend storing the user ID in the token (and doing ACL checks with the user id!) - and if the id is different, the signature must be different if you did not issue the token yourself, the signature will therefore not match. If that is your point, please let me know, and I will be happy to update my answer :)

Comment: How do I do it on laravel. Can you give some practical example?

Comment: I would not very much like to duplicate laravels documentation here. As it was pointed out in a comment to your question, you can do this with laravels Gate/Auth system. Access rights are called "abilities" here, and you find plenty of examples in [the documentation (checking abilities)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#checking-abilities).